# horizontal scroll menu in iphone?

Tags: iphone, menu, scroll, swipe

[image]

i want to create exact screen like above... should display horizontal scroll options below the product(mobile) image.

and the screen should have swipe feature when swipe to left it shows next product(mobile) 
how to design this? which controller to use

can i use tab view for horizontal menu??

please give some examples and ideas.....

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need a UITabViewController to manage the different sections.

The UITabViewController manages a bunch of view controllers (one for every tab).  One of those will be a UIViewController managing a UIScrollView.

Have a look at th e apple documentation for both those controllers and the UIScrollView.  Scroll view has a property to activate paging.